# Unable to Revoke Applications From Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, security

I have been attempting for the last week to *temporarily* remove some apps that I have provided read/write access to act on behalf of myself, but I am not having any success.

As you can see in the below gif, I am clicking on the "Remove" link, some cases multiple times, with no success.

The location of the page that I am attempting to revoke app access is:  `/users/apps/<UID>`

> [image]

I should mention that this is a security issue, as if (in an admittingly unlikely event) that an app decides to go haywire and is being destructive, I cannot revoke its access at this time.

I should also point out that I do not permanently want to remove any of these apps, I was wanting to do some debugging as a couple of these apps don't seem to hold authorization tokens properly.

---

Comment: **Console:** `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Comment: Yeah... also reported on: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307852/cant-remove-applications